# Sequence labeling with Keras - ignore first K predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm trying to create a sequence labeler for some long sequences.

Due to the nature of the problem, I don't expect the network to perform very well at the beginning of the sequence, due to a lack of historical data.

How can I train the network to ignore the first `k` predictions?

My network strucutre is as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10,return_sequences = True, input_shape = (None, 5)))
model.add(LSTM(10,return_sequences = True))
model.add(LSTM(10,return_sequences = True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')))

model.compile(optimizer = adam,loss = 'binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['acc'])
```

And I train it by doing: `model.fit(X,y)` where `X.shape` is `(m,n,5)` and `y.shape` is `(m,n,1)` where `m` is number of sequences and `n` is the sequence length

Comment: What do you mean to ignore? Do you want to skip the optimization part?

Comment: Ignoring them at the optimization, as you need to forward prop them to compute the next values and losses